# Expected a JSON object, array or literal

Tags: javascript, json

I have 3 files,

1. index.html
2. js/main.js
3. json.json

File name "json.json" having this line of code

```
data =    '[
           {"name":"John","guests":3,"status":"true"},
           {"name":"Mike","guests":5,"status":"false"},
           {"name":"Jenny","guests":2,"status":"false"}
           ]';
```

and here I am having following error
"Expected a JSON object, array or literal"

Please help me out from this.

Comment: That's *not* a JSON file.

Comment: Where is this error being output from? We need to see your code on main.js

Comment: I am following a tutorial in which he used to do this exact same thing to do the desired task

Comment: Maybe you could show the code that consumes this file — the one that's producing the error.

Comment: Post the link of the tutorial if you can not post the js file. You need to use the 'data' variable as json string.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a text format. It doesn't contain any code, like variable assigments. Your JSON file ought to just contain this text:

```
[
       {"name":"John","guests":3,"status":"true"},
       {"name":"Mike","guests":5,"status":"false"},
       {"name":"Jenny","guests":2,"status":"false"}
       ]
```

You can then read that from Javascript and convert it to the actual array it represents. Or, alternatively, you could just have had `var data = ...` in your file and saved it as a JS file. But Javascript is not the same thing as JSON, even though they are closely related.

Comment: okay I want to get that json file into a main.js file and display results. I am using JSON.parse(data) but it is not working.! they said data is not defined now using your apporach first I have to get JSON into main,js file and then parse this json file to get javascript object. But how can I do this?

Comment: more precisely, how can I get that JSON into my js variable ?

Comment: @Dr.Bakar - you request the data from the server via Ajax. You can do this with `fetch` (if your browser supports ES6) (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or `XMLHttpRequest` - or if you use jQuery you can use `$.ajax` or, specifically for JSON data, `$.getJson`: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/